# Show Activity When Screen is locked like "Viber", "Line" appliaction

Tags: android, screen-lock

As you know, in applications like "Viber", "Line" and ..., when new message receive by device, new activity, will popup-up and show the message to user, even the screen is locked but the lock-screen won't dismiss. This is happening even in "Xperia U" with android 2.3.7. I want to do the same thing in my application and I also tried to add the following Flag to my window:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

and also use wakelock, but it just turn the screen on without showing my application. So, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your lockscreen by using following code.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire();

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
```

Necessary Permission on manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />`

On onPause() or onDestroy().

```
wl.release();
```